# How can I round a number to the fourth decimal place without using round functions?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

This is what I've tried so far but I cannot figure out how to round to the fourth decimal place:

```c
162.3582 = (int)(162.3582 + 0.005);
printf("%.002f\n", 162.3582);
```

I'm trying to get 162.3600 but I'm getting 162.00 instead.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  That first line is invalid C syntax and won't compile.  That is, you can't assign to a literal value.

Comment: Are your variables of type `float` or `double`?  If `float`, you're probably in trouble already, because type `float` has the equivalent of approximately 7 decimal digits' worth of precision, so for numbers like 162.3582, the "fourth decimal place" is right where the inherent imprecision of type `float` kicks in.

Comment: How many places are you to try to round to, really?  You said 4, but the 162.36 you said you're shooting for looks more like 2 or 5 to me, depending on whether you're counting "places past the decimal" or "significant digits".

Comment: the number im trying to get is 162.3600 including the zeros, so i think its 4 decimal places

Comment: The number 162.3600 looks to me like it's *rounded* to 2 significant places, but then *printed* with four places.

Comment: `%.002f` is a very strange `printf` format.  It's equivalent to `%.2f`.  But it sounds like you want `%.4f`.

Comment: oh i see, yes that makes sense

Comment: The usual round-by-hand technique step involves four steps: (1) divide by the desired precision, (2) add 0.5; (3) convert to an integer (discard fractional pat); (4) multiply by the desired precision. For example: `double d = 162.3582; double d2 = (int)(d / 0.01 + 0.5) * 0.01;`.  This is however significantly imperfect in that it only works for positive numbers.  Also, instead of casting to `(int)`, it may be preferable to call the `floor()` function: `d2 = floor(d / 0.01 + 0.5) * 0.01;`.

Comment: im utterly lost, thank you for trying to help me though have a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe look at it like this (I'm just unpacking Steve Summit's comment):

```
double d = 162.3582;  // original value
d *= 100;  // shift decimal point right, giving 16235.82
// Note this is equivalent to Steve Summit's divide by .01
d += .5;   // add one half, giving 16236.32
d = (int)d;  // discard fraction, giving 16236.0
// Or use floor(d) as Steve Summit suggested (he's a genuine C expert)
d /= 100.0   // shift decimal point back, giving 162.36
// Equivalent to Summit's * 0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I round a number to the fourth decimal place without using round functions?

The *trick* is usually to scale the value by 10<sup>4</sup>, add 0.5, cast to some *integer* type, and the divide 10<sup>4</sup>

```
// Weak code
double pow10 = 10000.0;
double r1 = x * pow10;  
r1 += 0.5;
int i = (int) r1;
double r2  = i / pow10;
```

Problems:

- `x * pow10` may overflow.
- `x * pow10` may form an inexact product, tainting further calculations.
- `r1 += 0.5;` may form an inexact sum, tainting further calculations.
- `r1 += 0.5;` should be -0.5 for negative numbers.
- `int i = (int) r1;` is *undefined* behavior when `r1` is much outside `int` range.
- `i / pow10;` may form an inexact quotient.  Some values like 0.0001, may not be exactly representable as a `double`, yet the division should get closest.

Some improvements:

```
// a little better code
long double pow10 = 10000.0L;
long double r1 = x * pow10;  
r1 = r1 + (signbit(x) ? -0.5 : 0.5);
long double i = truncl(r1); // not floor
double r2  = (double) (i / pow10);
```

- Above code is just as weak when `long double` range/precision same as `double`.

---

If saddled with the dubious "without using round functions" requirement, consider printing:

```
sprintf(buf_of suffcient_size, "%.*f", 4, x);
double r2 = atof(buf_of suffcient_size);
```